# How is <%= form_tag ... do %> implemented?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm trying to figure out how you can herald a Ruby block in a <%= ... %> emitter.

No problem with the '<% form_tag do %>' part, but as I dig into Rails internals
and see how it uses erb to process templates, the generated Ruby code is invalid,
due to that hanging 'do'.  Is there a post-processor hiding in Rails somewhere that
straightens out the code before running it?  If yes, where is it?  If no, how does
Rails pull HTML and Ruby code out of this form?

Comment: The part after the `do` is a block. It's quite a hard concept. I don't know what you mean by 'invalid', 'hiding' or 'straighten out the code` but maybe you should be a little more specific.

Comment: I believe youwant to hagve a look at the presenter pattern. http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch?view=comments

Comment: What does herald mean Mr 38% ?

Comment: Michael, I used "herald" in a more-or-less regular English sense. It's not used much, but it's a better term than "introduce" or "designate" or "make way for". flpgr's link below answers exactly what I was wondering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails added a [hack](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb#L17) which uses a regular expression to figure out if what is passed to erb is a block expression and then handle it differently.

For a more detailed explanation: http://timelessrepo.com/block-helpers-in-rails3